# Express router file has a TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, express, typescript2.0, tsc

I have the following module format:

```
import * as express from 'express';
let router = express.Router();

router.post('/foo', function(req,res,next){
    // ...
});

export = router;
```

but I am getting this error:

[image]

This is driving me crazy - how can I get rid of this warning/error?

I am on these versions:

```
"express": "~4.14.1",
"@types/express": "^4.11.1",
```

and `tsc -v` => `Version 2.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of the error, but I don't know why

```
import * as express from 'express';
let router = express.Router() as express.Router;
```

seems very unnecessary to have to do that.

Like I said I am on these versions:

```
"express": "~4.14.1",
"@types/express": "^4.11.1",
```

and `tsc -v` => `Version 2.7.2`